# Как прописать путь к папке название которой определяется пременной?

Tags: pascal

В папке 3 будет создаваться папка 4, а в папке 4 папка 5. Название папок 4 и 5 будут вводится через переменную. Путь для создания папки 4 заранее известен (C:папка1папка2папка3), а вот как прописать путь для создания папки 5 если ещё не известно название папки 4?

```
var a, c : string;
b, d : string;

begin

c := 'C:\папка1\папка2\папка3';
d := ''; {как здесь путь прописать?}
Writeln('название папки 4'); Readln(а);
Writeln('название папки 5'); Readln(b);

MkDir(c+'\'+a);

end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо ничего прописывать. `d` - лишняя переменная.

```
MkDir(c+'\'+a+'\'+b); // MkDir(c+'\'+a); - достаточно одного вызова
```